# How does Ember Data deal with security of cached objects?

Tags: security, ember.js, memoization

From what I understand, ember data is a memoization engine; invoking `peekAll` looks for cached data rather than making an expensive network call. But where are these data cached? If these data are loaded client-side, doesn't that mean the data is "in transit"? If I want to design a secure front end application that holds sensitive data for the least amount of time, how can I do this? Should I avoid using Ember data entirely and simply force back end calls to be made?

Comment: you can `unload` data from the ED-store.

Comment: There's no "secure" front end that runs in the web. There's just varying degrees of less insecure. Clearing the items from the cache is better than nothing (and that's totally possible in ED). But, in the web, you can't certificate pin, XSS is possible, there are man in the browser attacks, and many more sophisticated ways to leak that data. At the end of the day, what you can send to an insecure front end is a matter of risk analysis, legal regulations, and your own appetite for risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ED stores data in memory. You may just use ajax calls but you will store results in memory as well so security level is pretty much the same in both cases. When you reload page in browser (f5) - that cached data is gone. Also, accessing data from outside of your app is not that trivial

Comment: Can you elaborate, from a security standpoint, what you mean by "not-that-trivial"? When you say it's cleared when you hit <F5> does that mean there's a browser mechanism that's holding the cache? If I were a malicious user how would I gain access to the ED cache?

Comment: @franklin ember data just stores data in memory. Internally it does something like `var data = { /*some data*/ }`.

Comment: So I'd have to attack the internal memory of the client in order to access data in the store?

Comment: @franklin something like that. Probably, XSS attack might work or malicious browser extension (i.e. Ember Inspector has some way to access store, so probably it is possible to write some extension targeted against your app)